# Comparing user input with stored data from database, and ask what to do if they do not match?

Tags: php, compare, prompt

In the process of checkout, the user might start filling out the mailing/billing form before realizing that they should login - if they're an returning customer. *(It's a highlightet area at the top telling them to do so, but you can't be too certain they use it.)*

**The scenario is like this:**
The user is checking out. They start filling out the form. Then they remembers that they already have an account with the company, or notices the "sign in" notice at the top, and then logs in.
Now, when the user is logged in, we want to populate the form for the returning customer to make the process faster, but we don't want to overwrite whatever the user already typed. So we need to do some comapring on the fields, and then ask if the user want's to change or keep. Also, we do not whish to prompt the user if there's no difference.

My first though was to take all not empty fields into a combined string, and use `strcasecmp()` to  compare it with an equal string from database. But turns out php don't think "y" and "Y" is the same letter, so it produces a mismatch. Also, since this is a Norwegian site, the use of nordic characters (e.g "æ ø å") is making this rather difficult..

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished in a good way?

Comment: You will probably have to do this with a cookie. Use Javascript to grab what the user has entered in these fields when they click the login button, store that data in a cookie and then compare/manipulate it when they are logged in if this data is present on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is html local storage so that if user fills a form than browser will store the data till completion of form like stackoverflow.If due to some reason page the cancelled  or anything else reason got closed than you can just get that data and fill the form again with that data so that no time will consume .This is a very good technique you can store up to 5 mb on local machine without any server side call.

for further detail see this

[html5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

[Local storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)

Answer (score 0):

When you take your not empty fields into a combined string

```
$_SESSION['checkoutForm_fields'] = $combinedFieldNames; // forexample comma seperated or json_encoded()
$_SESSION['checkoutForm_value'] = md5($combinedString);
// After login complete and you fetch the old values from DB
// get the $_SESSION['checkoutForm_fields'] value and gather the values of these fields from DB lets say $combinedStringFromDB;
if ($_SESSION['checkoutForm_value'] != md5($combinedStringFromDB)) {
    // Do what ever you want.
}
```